# Anonymous/Community User's suggested edits right is banned because of too many rejected edits?

Tags: feature-request, support, suggested-edits, community-user

When I tried to test a suggeseted edit on Meta as Anonymous, I got.

```
Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.
```

So, Community User's edit rights are revoked due to too many edits by anonymous users among the world?

I didn't do too many suggests (only one today) myself, so the error is not because of my suggestions alone I guess.

**Edit**: Added feature-request to mod tools according to waffles's comment, although I have no clue at all about what it is.

> I totally need to add logging here for mods, so we can see list of IPs rejected with reasons. perhaps change this to a feature request around mod tools? – waffles♦

Comment: No issue for me; getting a nice and warm "Thanks for your edit!
This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed." [for this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/533). Note that (now) it says *"Anonymous had 0 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected."* though. Not sure if that matters?

Comment: @Arjan, yeah, strange then.

Comment: Maybe this is per IP, or IP range?

Comment: @Pekka, could be. probably I got someone else IP or got into that IP range, with last edit right then. :D I can click edit button, and I got this error when I tried to save it. But now the error show me right away, when I click edit button.

Comment: How do you anonymously edit? I tried opening this post in "incognito" mode, and I don't have an edit button?

Comment: @Jon, that can only done with old questions (I think 6 or 8 hours old, IIRC)

Comment: OK - I just successfully edited a 13hr old question as anonymous. Obviously, YOU has been trolling as anonymous and has been IP banned as a result. Shame on YOU.

Comment: @Jon, I only tried once, and it does not even goes into suggested list. Its not my fault :-)

Comment: I totally need to add logging here for mods, so we can see list of IPs rejected with reasons. perhaps change this to a feature request around mod tools?