# Losing the ability to suggest edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, edit-ban

On Stack Overflow, I've lost my permission to edit other's questions, and after reading some posts (like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173140/editing-questions/173141#173141)), I guess it's because I have made too many "minor edits". I think [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1779475) is the last one guilty.

My problem here is that I can only "guess" why I've been suspended my privilege, and when did it happen, which edits led me here so I can learn from my mistakes, how long will it last...

**My questions are:**

- Is a notification to the user that his editing privilege has been suspended a good idea?
- Are there some information about my suspension on Stack Overflow that I haven't discovered?
- Is there some place in FAQ where the suspension's rules are explained?

*Note: I've seen [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123718/allow-adding-a-reject-reason-when-marking-an-edit-as-not-helpful-in-the-improv), [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89817/anonymous-community-users-suggested-edits-right-is-banned-because-of-too-many-r), and finally [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor?rq=1) which proposed the notification feature, to which my question is closely related.*

Comment: There are no explanations on the rules for suspension, as having such information would enable users to game the system. Basically, cheat.

Comment: @J.Steen I get that. But there are some basics explanations, like how long are you suspended, and since when, and just the general reason so I can improve myself. This doesn't allow cheating, and I would find useful to have such information!

Comment: The first time you're suspended from edits is for 7 days. I believe it escalates if you're banned more times.

Comment: @J.Steen Alright, good to know! I don't know where you got this information though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I can't provide an official link - I just can't find one. Maybe someone else can chip in?

Comment: @J.Steen You're confusing *being banned from posting some kind of post (either questions or answsers* with *being banned from editing*. The former never expires automatically (you have to improve your posts to get out of it) and its details are secret to prevent gaming the system. The second expires in a relatively short time (at first, 7 days), and as far as I know, nobody has ever said its details need to be secret--to the extent they're not clearly explicated, this is probably just because nobody has bothered to do so, or maybe the details change rapidly.

Comment: @EliahKagan To be honest, I'm *not* confusing the two, I was just under the impression that the suggestion-edit-ban-algo was *also* secret to prevent gaming - just as for the post-ban-algo. =)

Comment: @J.Steen What would it *mean* for someone to try to game the edit ban? People don't submit edits with the intention of them being rejected, and unlike the question/answer ban, there's nothing you can do during an edit ban that affects the ban in any way. The only thing people could figure out would be how close together the bad edits have to be. How would people game the system with that information? By making sure to insert additional *good* edits in between their bad edits, to make themselves look like better editors *by actually being better editors?* Mission accomplished.

Comment: @EliahKagan I didn't say it made sense. I just said I wasn't confusing anything with something else. Please invalidate my (somewhat unbased) argument for obscuring the algorithm, I'm fine with that. ;)

Comment: Some time back I lost the small rep award that accompanied a good edit, and it was NEVER restored.  But they did not remove the capability for me to edit, presumably because they were good edits.  So go figure!

Comment: @GarryVass Presumably you gained enough rep (2k) that you don't need to have your edits approved anymore; along with that you don't get the +2 rep for doing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get banned from suggesting edits if [too many of your recent suggested edits were rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337) ([rejections by Community don't count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137611/suggested-edit-rejections-for-concurrent-edits-should-not-count-for-the-suggeste/182983#182983)). The ban lasts 7 days.

You can browse your suggestions in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437016/bigood?tab=activity&sort=suggestions). Unfortunately, there's no way to filter the rejected suggestions only.

You can get a list of your rejected suggested edits in a machine-parseable format [from the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-suggested-edits): select “rejection” on the “sort” criterion. You can do the same [for another user as well](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-on-users): enter the user ID into the “ids” box. [Here](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-on-users#order=desc&sort=creation&ids=1437016&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true)'s a direct link to your rejected edits. You can query older edits in the [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) as well: [List a user's rejected suggested edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/128440/list-a-users-rejected-suggested-edits), [List votes on a user's rejected suggested edits](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/128443/list-votes-on-a-users-rejected-suggested-edits). Unfortunately there's no way to retrieve the rejection reasons from the API or the data explorer.

Answer (score 7):

You can go through your suggestions and look at old edits, like [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1757063). It corrects a typo in the code that changes what the code does. **That's not what edits are for!** That should be in a comment instead.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1437016/bigood?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) you can see all your suggestions.

Comment: Yes, this one is really no good. In fact, I can see all my suggestions, but can't browse my rejected edits. It could be discouraging to have to browse all the edits to find the rejected ones.

Comment: @Bigood Yes, there was a feature request here on Meta Stack Overflow for that, but I think it got declined unfortunately.

Comment: @Bigood I agree it should be easier to view one's edits by whether they were rejected or accepted. (Being able to see edits that were *improved*, whether marked helpful or not, would also be highly valuable, as it would help people to learn specifically what sorts of things they could do better while editing.) But with a temporary edit ban like you have, the rejected edits are going to be at or near the top of the list. If you look at your most recent edit suggestions, you can probably find all the recently rejected ones easily. Also, you should look at accepted edits that were edited again.

Comment: @EliahKagan I'll check my edits this way so, introspection time!

Comment: @Doorknob No, correcting a typo in the code is what edits are for. Please read the [editing guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and the [comment guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (“When shouldn't I comment? (…) Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit”). What happened here was probably that the author changed `:checked` to `:selected` during the 5-minute grace window, but Bigood had started his suggested edit before. Unfortunately the user experience in this case sucks.

Comment: @Gilles Changing the function of the code should not be done in a suggested edit - it should be a comment instead.

Comment: @Doorknob No, again, *correcting* the code should be done in an edit. Proposing an alternate solution should be done in a separate answer. In neither case is a comment appropriate. Comments are for unresolved issues, when you aren't sure if something is wrong or how to fix it. Please, read the editing and commenting guidelines.

Comment: @Gilles Suggested edits should not change what the code does - that is a clearly established rule.

Comment: @Doorknob No, there is no such rule (it sometimes comes up on [metase], but with no basis whatsoever). Again, **[read the official guidelines](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)**.

Comment: @Gilles "To clarify the meaning of the post **(without changing that meaning)**"

Comment: @Doorknob *sigh* Correcting a typo does not change the meaning. Obviously, if you propose a different solution, that does change the meaning, but it's not what we're discussing here. As this argument is rather sterile, I won't be replying any more, feel free to have the last word.

Comment: @Gilles Well, if the code foos the bar, and you fix a typo so now it foos the baz, the meaning has changed, correct? I do agree that this has gotten a bit... long-winded, so I will stop commenting here as well :P